# Print 3rd line from the bottom in stdout

Tags: linux, python-2.7, tkinter, stdout, readline

Currently i am running this

```
while p.poll() is None:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    print output,
```

What is happening is all the lines are being printed. What i am looking for is to print, usually the ***3rd line*** from the bottom, which contains data on whether the command has executed properly or not.

Additionally is there a way to have like a status bar at the bottom that updates real time using ***Tkinter Label***

Comment: store the output in a list, only print out the third last element of the list (indice -3 works fine)

Comment: also you are asking two completely seperates questions with the one post, both of which are just "how do i do ___" which suggests you didn't try very hard before posting.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thanks for the tip, i wasn't aware that the stdout can be migrated into a list.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen i'll try to rephrase the question next time to include all the research that i have done prior to posting.

Comment: because of how python works you could put bound methods in a list if you really wanted too, and for the time-label you can look at [this reference](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/629499-dynamically-displaying-time-using-tkinter-label)

Comment: could you post the solution as an answer then accept your own answer, it would work better for the mechanics of this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, thanks to @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen tip

To print only the third last line (indice -3) in terminal shell window

```
import Tkinter as *
import subprocess

out = []  # Create empty list
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    out.append(line.rstrip('\n')) # append list
print out[-3] # print item in the list, in this case -3
```

Or to display in tkinter label

```
import Tkinter as *
import subprocess

out = []  # Create empty list
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    out.append(line.rstrip('\n')) # append list
window = Tk()
Label(window, text=out[-3]).grid(sticky=W)
```

Comment: for loops that only append to a list are the whole reason [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) exists: `out = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,'')]`